# How to Mock FileSystem function

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I do not know how to mock the section where I'm changing the file's owner from line `Path path = newFile.toPath();` to the end.

Here's my function :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String uploadEndpoint(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                 @RequestParam("usernameSession") String usernameSession,
                                 @RequestHeader("current-folder") String folder) throws IOException {


        String[] pathArray = file.getOriginalFilename().split("[\\\\\\/]");
        String originalName = pathArray[pathArray.length-1];
        LOGGER.info("Upload triggerred with : {} , filename : {}", originalName, file.getName());
        String workingDir = URLDecoder.decode(folder.replace("!", "."),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
                .replace("|", File.separator);
        LOGGER.info("The file will be moved to : {}", workingDir);
        File newFile = new File(workingDir + File.separator + originalName);
        //UserPrincipal owner = Files.getOwner(newFile.toPath());

        file.transferTo(newFile);

        Path path = newFile.toPath();
        FileOwnerAttributeView foav = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
        UserPrincipal owner = foav.getOwner();
        System.out.format("Original owner  of  %s  is %s%n", path, owner.getName());

        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        UserPrincipalLookupService upls = fs.getUserPrincipalLookupService();

        UserPrincipal newOwner = upls.lookupPrincipalByName(usernameSession);
        foav.setOwner(newOwner);

        UserPrincipal changedOwner = foav.getOwner();
        System.out.format("New owner  of  %s  is %s%n", path,
                changedOwner.getName());

        return "ok";
    }
```

And here's the test :

```
@Test
    public void uploadEndpointTest() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(file);
        Mockito.when(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()).thenReturn("src/test/resources/download/test.txt");
        assertEquals("ok", fileExplorerController.uploadEndpoint(multipartFile, "userName", "src/test/resources/download"));
    }
```

I got an exception because "userName" is not a user. I'd like to mock the call where it looks for a match in windows's users. It works when I set my window's username instead of "userName", but I can't let my window's username.

I tried to mock `fs.getUserPrincipalLookupService()`; and `upls.lookupPrincipalByName(usernameSession);` but I do not know what to return to mock the call.

Many thanks !

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should consider the [Single Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and further dissect your code.

Meaning: create a *helper* class that *abstracts* all these low level file system accesses for you. Then you provide a *mocked* instance of that helper class here, and you simply ensure that the helper method gets called with the expected parameters. That will make your service method `uploadEndpoint()` much easier to test.

And then, your *new* helper class could simply expect a File object. And that enables you to **pass** a **mocked** File object to it, and all of a sudden you are in control of what `thatMockedFileObject.newPath()` will return.

In other words: your first goal should be to write code that doesn't make use of `static` or `new()` in a way that prevents simple mocking using Mockito. Whenever you encounter situations where you think "I need PowerMock(ito) to test my production code", then the very first impulse should be: "I should avoid that, and improve my design".

Same for `FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();` ... instead of trying to get into the "mock that static call business", you make sure that your helper classes **accept** some FileSystem instance. And all of a sudden you can pass a simple Mockito mock object, and you are in full control over it.

Comment: @J-Alex I think it could be shorter, but it is always about balancing: not enough effort, not enough upvotes flowing back ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I followed your advices and it works, I will think the tests differently now ;)

Comment: @Majestic can you add your changed class as an answer here? It would be interesting to see the result after refactoring